# Spark UI data without web access

Tags: apache-spark

Is it possible to access run data without the Spark UI Webpage?

I am running Spark on an HPC cluster. I ssh to the login node and then submit jobs to run on compute nodes. AFAICT, I do not have web access to ports on these compute nodes from my laptop so I have no way to access the Spark UI Webpage. Is there an alternative way to access run information during or after a run?

For example, I see that there is a [Spark History Server](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#viewing-after-the-fact) that I can use to view run details after a run. Is it possible to copy files from the HPC cluster to my laptop and run the history server locally to analyse the run details?